How to obtain orthonormal eigenvectors for spectral decomposition?
Considering the symmetric matrix
$$
\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
13 & -4 & 2 \\
-4 & 13 & -2 \\
2 & -2 & 10
\end{array}\right]
$$
The eigenvalues obtained from the characteristic equation $|\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I}|=0$ are $\lambda_1=9, \lambda_2=9$, and $\lambda_3=18$.
How to obtain the orthonormal eigenvectors? I need to find two eigenvectors for $\lambda = 9$, but I don't know the step-by-step process to obtain these two orthonormal eigenvectors. Is there a procedure for this? Any tips for it?

Apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the two eigenvectors you get for $\lambda = 9$.

We could also take advantage of the cross-product since we're in 3 dimensional space. The two vectors you're after form a basis of the orthogonal complement to $\text{span}{(2,-2,1)}$. You could begin with one vector $\mathbf v$ that is orthogonal to $(2,-2,1)$ (such as $\mathbf v = (1,1,0)$) and then use the cross-product to get a second. For my example, you would get
$$
(2,-2,1) \times (1,1,0) = (-1,1,4).
$$
normalizing these vectors gives you
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0), \quad \frac 1{3\sqrt{2}} (-1,1,4).
$$
